# Pandas dataframe overwrite object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to overwrite the matrix I have of dimensions n to matrix of dimensions m (n>m). Intuitive code like this does not work:

```
sigmaSmall = sigmaSmall.loc[indices, indices]
```

How can I do it in 1 line?

Comment: are your columns labeled as what you have in `indices`?

Comment: yes, it is covariance matrix. indices=columns

Comment: Can you post a sample dataframe and how you want your output to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd dimension takes column names, not numbered indices.
So instead do:

`sigmaSmall = sigmaSmall.loc[indices, sigmaSmall.columns[indices]]`

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your indicies are make it hard to tell, but it should look something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], columns=['a','b','c'])
df.loc[0:1, ['a','b']]
```

Where the second argument is the column names that you want to select